# In C++ can one rename/alias a non-namespace, non-class name?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-declaration

I have

```
namespace src {
   struct src_bar;
   void src_baz();
   template<class T> class src_qux;
}
```

which I'd like to reference as

```
namespace dst {
    struct dst_bar;
    void dst_baz();
    template<class T> class dst_qux;
}
```

meaning that I'd like to "rename" or "alias" or "relabel" names from `src`.

For `dst_bar` one can of course use `namespace dst { typedef src_bar dst_bar; }`.  Is there some (non-macro) equivalent allowing me to rename `src::src_baz` as `dst::dst_baz` and `src::src_qux` as `dst::dst_qux`?

Unless I'm mistaken, neither a `using` statement nor a namespace alias can accomplish the other two.  Writing templated forwarding functions for `dst_baz()` is a possibility but requires knowledge of the arity of `src_baz`.  Template typedefs could have `dst_qux<T>::type` be `src_qux<T>` but the indirection adds verbosity.

FWIW, my use case is taking C names like `somepackage_someportion_somefuncA` and providing a namespaced-friendly version `somepackage::someportion::somefuncA` so that other folks can employ `using somepackage::someportion` for brevity.

Comment: Is `#define` viable option for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions you will have to manually forward the requests. For non-template types you can just typedef. For template types, y can use the new `using` feature of c++11 To create a typedef-style alias for a template, if your compiler supports it, or else you are basically out of luck.

Comment: This is what I expected.  Thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot "rename" something so that it no longer uses its original name.

However, you can get the same effect via trickery.

First, import the header for the defines you want to corral *inside a namespace block*:

```
namespace foo {
    #include "src_stuff.h"
}
```

Now you have `foo::src::src_bar` and friends.

Then, use `typedef` liberally:

```
namespace bar {
    typedef foo::src::src_bar dst_bar;
}
```

Voila, you've got a `bar::dst_bar` which is the same as `src::src_bar` would have been. If you don't care about the definitions remaining available under the old names in addition, skip the first step and just make `typedef`s for convenience. That's what they're for, after all.

Comment: Enclosing the included file in a namespace is bound to be problematic... The implementation file for that header will not have the namespace and will thus define different functions than those declared in the so-included header. And this does not tackled the main part of the question: how to do the equivalent of the typedefs for functions and templates.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The templates don't actually interfere with the `typedef` approach. You can even use preprocessor macros if they get too long.

Answer (score 0):

If usage of macros is an acceptable option for you then here is one solution:

```
// declare this macro in some common file
#define CREATE(SCOPE) \
namespace SCOPE { \
   struct SCOPE## _bar; \
   void SCOPE## _baz(); \
   template<class T> class SCOPE## _qux; \
}
```

Usage:

```
CREATE(src);
CREATE(dst);
```

Comment: Thank you for the macro-based solution.